# Is a quality control system proper use of the rails Paper Trails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I am using rails 4 and have built a system where my users can create a "blog" and then that "blog", it's attributes, and relationships are reviewed by other users.  They can be adjusted by the reviewers.  I am building my own QualityReview model that has many MarkUps but then I came across Paper Trail https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail and it seems like I could maybe just let users make updates right to the model and then just go back and forth with the model history if reviews were shown to be invalid.

Has anyone used PaperTrail for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail

This gem is introduced thoroughly in Railscast, which I think it can do what you want to achieve.

Simply build a version model and a versions controller, and use an index page to list all the versions belongs to a specific blog item, with their details in the show page.